# Issue with updating progress data accurately in a quiz (Android Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile

I am developing an android application (quiz feature) where I store progress data after a user completes a quiz. However, I am encountering several problems with the saveProgress function responsible for updating various metrics.

Problem Description:

Incorrect Answers Issue:
The total incorrect answers (totalWrongAnswers) are consistently being reported as 0 and not updating correctly, even when providing non-zero values for incorrect answers. This discrepancy leads to inaccurate progress tracking.

Optimal Update Implementation:
Despite several revisions, I am unable to identify the root cause leading to incorrect answers not being updated correctly within the total questions answered. I aim to implement a solution that ensures the total correct, total incorrect, and total questions answered are maintained accurately.

```
package com.mtcdb.stem.mathtrix.quiz

import android.content.*
import android.util.*
import java.io.*

object QuizProgressStorage {

    private const val PROGRESS_FILE_NAME = "quiz_progress.txt"

    fun saveProgress(
        context : Context,
        selectedDifficulty : String,
        totalQuestionsAnswered : Int,
        totalCorrectAnswers : Int,
        totalWrongAnswers : Int,
    ) {
        try {
            val file = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), PROGRESS_FILE_NAME)
            val progressDataMap = loadProgress(context).toMutableMap()

            val progressData = progressDataMap[selectedDifficulty] ?: listOf(0, 0, 0)

            val totalQuestions = progressData[0] + totalQuestionsAnswered
            val totalCorrect = progressData[1] + totalCorrectAnswers
            val totalIncorrect = progressData[2] + totalWrongAnswers

            progressDataMap[selectedDifficulty] =
                listOf(totalQuestions, totalCorrect, totalIncorrect)

            file.bufferedWriter().use { out ->
                progressDataMap.forEach { (key, value) ->
                    out.write("$key:${value.joinToString(",")}\n")
                }
            }
        } catch (e : Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.e("QuizProgressStorage", "Failed to save progress data.")
        }
    }

    fun loadProgress(context : Context) : MutableMap<String, List<Int>> {
        val file = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), PROGRESS_FILE_NAME)
        val progressDataMap = mutableMapOf<String, List<Int>>()

        if (file.exists()) {
            file.bufferedReader().useLines { lines ->
                lines.forEach { line ->
                    val dataParts = line.split(":")
                    val difficulty = dataParts[0]
                    val values = dataParts[1].split(",")
                        .map { it.trim().toInt() } // Trim whitespace before parsing
                    progressDataMap[difficulty] = values
                }
            }
        }

        return progressDataMap
    }

    fun loadAverageScores(context : Context) : Map<String, Double> {
        val progressDataMap = loadProgress(context)
        val averageScores = mutableMapOf<String, Double>()

        for ((difficulty, data) in progressDataMap) {
            val totalCorrectAnswers = data.getOrNull(1) ?: 0
            val totalQuestionsAnswered = data.getOrNull(0) ?: 1
            val averageScore =
                if (totalQuestionsAnswered != 0) totalCorrectAnswers.toDouble() / totalQuestionsAnswered else 0.0
            averageScores[difficulty] = averageScore
        }

        return averageScores
    }

    // Calculate the total values across all difficulties
    fun calculateTotalValues(progressDataMap : Map<String, List<Int>>) : List<Int> {
        var totalQuestions = 0
        var totalCorrectAnswers = 0
        var totalWrongAnswers = 0

        progressDataMap.values.forEach { data ->
            totalQuestions += data.getOrNull(0) ?: 0
            totalCorrectAnswers += data.getOrNull(1) ?: 0
            totalWrongAnswers += data.getOrNull(2) ?: 0
        }

        return listOf(totalQuestions, totalCorrectAnswers, totalWrongAnswers)
    }
}
```

The data will come from here:

```
package com.mtcdb.stem.mathtrix.quiz

import android.annotation.*
import android.database.sqlite.*
import android.graphics.*
import android.os.*
import android.view.*
import android.widget.*
import androidx.fragment.app.*
import androidx.lifecycle.*
import com.akexorcist.roundcornerprogressbar.*
import com.google.android.material.radiobutton.*
import com.mtcdb.stem.mathtrix.R
import java.util.*

@Suppress("NAME_SHADOWING")
class QuizFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var questionTextView : TextView
    private lateinit var optionsRadioGroup : RadioGroup
    private lateinit var dbHelper : QuizDbHelper
    private lateinit var tVQuestions : TextView
    private lateinit var database : SQLiteDatabase
    private var questions : MutableList<QuizEntity> = mutableListOf()
    private var currentQuestionIndex = 0
    private lateinit var timerTextView : TextView
    private lateinit var timerProgressBar : RoundCornerProgressBar
    private var selectedOptionIndex = -1
    private var countDownTimer : CountDownTimer? = null
    private var timeLeftMillis : Long = 300000 // 5 minutes in milliseconds
    private val totalTimeMillis : Long = 300000 // 5 minutes in milliseconds
    private var totalQuestionsPerGame = 10
    private var questionsAnswered = 0
    private var quizStartTimeMillis : Long = 0
    private lateinit var sharedViewModel : SharedViewModel

    private var totalQuestionsAnswered = 0
    private var totalCorrectAnswers = 0
    private var totalWrongAnswers = 0


    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater : LayoutInflater, container : ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState : Bundle?,
    ) : View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_quiz, container, false)

        // Initialize sharedViewModel
        sharedViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity())[SharedViewModel::class.java]

        // Initialize totalQuestionsAnswered and totalCorrectAnswers in the SharedViewModel
        sharedViewModel.totalQuestionsAnswered.value = 0
        sharedViewModel.totalCorrectAnswers.value = 0

        timerTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.timerTextView)
        questionTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.questionTextView)
        optionsRadioGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.optionsRadioGroup)
        timerProgressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.timerProgress)
        tVQuestions = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_questions)

        // Display the first question
        fetchQuestions()
        displayQuestion()

        dbHelper = QuizDbHelper(requireContext())
        database = dbHelper.writableDatabase

        val totalQuestions = questions.size
        val currentQuestionNumber = currentQuestionIndex + 1
        quizStartTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()

        view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_progress)?.text = buildString {
            append("Question ")
            append(currentQuestionNumber)
        }
        tVQuestions.text = buildString {
            append("out of ")
            append(totalQuestions)
        }

        startTimer()

        return view
    }

    private fun displayQuestion() {
        // Check if questions are not empty before accessing their elements
        if (questions.isNotEmpty() && currentQuestionIndex < questions.size) {
            val currentQuestion = questions[currentQuestionIndex]

            questionTextView.text = currentQuestion.question
            optionsRadioGroup.removeAllViews()

            for ((index, option) in currentQuestion.options.withIndex()) {
                val radioButton = context?.let { MaterialRadioButton(it) }
                radioButton?.text = option
                radioButton?.id = index
                radioButton?.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.option_border_bg)
                radioButton?.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF000000"))
                radioButton?.setPadding(32, 16, 32, 16)

                val linearLayoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                )

                linearLayoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 32)

                radioButton?.layoutParams = linearLayoutParams
                optionsRadioGroup.addView(radioButton)

                // Set a listener for each RadioButton
                radioButton?.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
                    if (isChecked) {
                        // Highlight the selected option when the RadioButton is checked
                        selectedOptionIndex = index
                    } else {
                        radioButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.option_border_bg)
                    }
                }

                radioButton?.setOnClickListener {
                    checkAnswer(index)
                }
            }

            // Update the question number display
            updateQuestionNumber()
        } else {
            // Handle the case where questions are empty or all questions have been displayed
        }
    }


    // Function to update the question number display
    private fun updateQuestionNumber() {
        val currentQuestionNumber = currentQuestionIndex + 1

        view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_progress)?.text = buildString {
            append("Question ")
            append(currentQuestionNumber)
        }
    }

    private fun fetchQuestions() {
        dbHelper = QuizDbHelper(requireContext())
        database = dbHelper.writableDatabase

        // Determine the difficulty level
        val difficultyLevel = when (this.arguments?.getString("difficultyLevel")) {
            "Easy" -> "Easy"
            "Medium" -> "Medium"
            "Hard" -> "Hard"
            else -> "Easy"
        }// Default to Easy if difficulty level is not recognized

        totalQuestionsPerGame = when (difficultyLevel) {
            "Easy" -> 10
            "Medium" -> 15
            "Hard" -> 20
            else -> 10 // Default to 10 if difficulty level is not recognized
        }

        // Fetch questions based on the selected difficulty level
        val cursor = database.rawQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM ${QuizDbHelper.TABLE_QUIZ} WHERE ${QuizDbHelper.COLUMN_DIFFICULTY_LEVEL} = ? LIMIT ?",
            arrayOf(difficultyLevel, totalQuestionsPerGame.toString())
        )

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            // If there are questions in the cursor, convert them to a list of QuizEntity
            questions = mutableListOf()
            do {
                val idColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(QuizDbHelper.COLUMN_ID)
                val questionColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(QuizDbHelper.COLUMN_QUESTION)
                val optionsColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(QuizDbHelper.COLUMN_OPTIONS)
                val correctAnswerColumnIndex =
                    cursor.getColumnIndex(QuizDbHelper.COLUMN_CORRECT_ANSWER_INDEX)
                val difficultyLevelColumnIndex =
                    cursor.getColumnIndex(QuizDbHelper.COLUMN_DIFFICULTY_LEVEL)

                if (idColumnIndex >= 0 && questionColumnIndex >= 0 && optionsColumnIndex >= 0 && correctAnswerColumnIndex >= 0 && difficultyLevelColumnIndex >= 0) {
                    val id = cursor.getLong(idColumnIndex)
                    val question = cursor.getString(questionColumnIndex)
                    val options = cursor.getString(optionsColumnIndex).split(",")
                    val correctAnswerIndex = cursor.getInt(correctAnswerColumnIndex)
                    val difficultyLevel = cursor.getString(difficultyLevelColumnIndex)

                    val quizEntity = QuizEntity(
                        id, question, options, correctAnswerIndex, difficultyLevel
                    )
                    questions.add(quizEntity)
                } else {
                    // Handle the case where one or more columns are not found
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext())
            questions.shuffle()

            // Display the first question
            displayQuestion()
            updateQuestionNumber()
        } else {
            // Handle the case where there are no questions in the cursor
        }
        updateQuestionNumber()
        cursor.close()
    }

    private fun checkAnswer(selectedOptionIndex : Int) {
        if (selectedOptionIndex != -1) {
            if (questions.isNotEmpty() && currentQuestionIndex < questions.size) {
                questions[currentQuestionIndex].selectedAnswerIndex = selectedOptionIndex

                val correctAnswerIndex = questions[currentQuestionIndex].correctAnswerIndex

                if (selectedOptionIndex == correctAnswerIndex) {
                    // Mark option as correct
                    markOptionAsCorrect(selectedOptionIndex)

                    // Increment total correct answers
                    totalCorrectAnswers++
                } else {
                    // Mark option as incorrect
                    val correctOptionIndex = questions[currentQuestionIndex].correctAnswerIndex
                    markOptionAsIncorrect(selectedOptionIndex, correctOptionIndex)

                    // Increment total wrong answers
                    totalWrongAnswers++
                }

                // Increment the total questions answered only once per question
                totalQuestionsAnswered++


                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                    currentQuestionIndex++
                    optionsRadioGroup.clearCheck()

                    if (currentQuestionIndex < questions.size) {
                        // Clear and display the next question
                        clearOptionBackgrounds()
                        displayQuestion()
                    } else {
                        // End of the quiz
                        val score = calculateScore()
                        navigateToQuizResult(score)
                    }
                }, 1000) // Delay for 1 second before moving to the next question
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Please select an option.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    private fun clearOptionBackgrounds() {
        for (i in 0 until optionsRadioGroup.childCount) {
            optionsRadioGroup.getChildAt(i)?.background = null
        }
    }

    private fun markOptionAsCorrect(optionIndex : Int) {
        optionsRadioGroup.getChildAt(optionIndex)?.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.option_correct)
    }

    private fun markOptionAsIncorrect(selectedIndex : Int, correctIndex : Int) {
        val correctColor = R.drawable.option_correct
        val incorrectColor = R.drawable.option_wrong
        optionsRadioGroup.getChildAt(selectedIndex)?.setBackgroundResource(incorrectColor)
        optionsRadioGroup.getChildAt(correctIndex)?.setBackgroundResource(correctColor)
    }

    private fun calculateScore() : Int {
        var score = 0
        for (question in questions) {
            if (question.isAnswerCorrect) {
                score++
            }
        }
        return score
    }

    private fun moveNextOrEndQuiz() {
        clearOptionBackgrounds()
        optionsRadioGroup.clearCheck()
        if (questionsAnswered < totalQuestionsPerGame) {
            // Move to the next question
            currentQuestionIndex++
            questionsAnswered++
            displayQuestion()

            // Save progress data
            val selectedDifficulty = this.arguments?.getString("difficultyLevel") ?: "Easy"
            saveProgressData(
                selectedDifficulty,
                totalQuestionsPerGame,
                totalCorrectAnswers,
                totalWrongAnswers
            )
        } else {
            // End of the quiz
            val score = calculateScore()
            navigateToQuizResult(score)
        }
    }

    private fun startTimer() {
        // Cancel any existing timer to avoid overlapping
        countDownTimer?.cancel()

        // Create a new CountDownTimer
        countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(timeLeftMillis, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished : Long) {
                // Update the timer text
                timerTextView.text = buildString {
                    append("Time left: ")
                    append(formatTime(millisUntilFinished))
                }
                // Update the timer ProgressBar
                timerProgressBar.setProgress(((totalTimeMillis - millisUntilFinished) / 1000).toInt())
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                // Time's up, move to the next question or end the quiz
                moveNextOrEndQuiz()
            }
        }

        // Start the timer
        countDownTimer?.start()
    }

    private fun formatTime(millis : Long) : String {
        val minutes = millis / 60000
        val seconds = (millis % 60000) / 1000
        return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
    }

    private fun navigateToQuizResult(score : Int) {
        val resultFragment = QuizResultFragment()
        val difficulty = this.arguments?.getString("difficultyLevel")

        // Calculate time taken
        val quizEndTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val timeTakenMillis = quizEndTimeMillis - quizStartTimeMillis

        // Convert time taken to a formatted string (e.g., "03:30" for 3 minutes and 30 seconds)
        val formattedTimeTaken = formatTime(timeTakenMillis)

        // Pass the questions, difficulty, time taken, and score as arguments to the fragment
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("quizQuestions", ArrayList(questions))
        bundle.putInt("quizScore", score)
        bundle.putString("difficulty", difficulty)
        bundle.putString("timeTaken", formattedTimeTaken)
        resultFragment.arguments = bundle

        // Perform the fragment transaction
        requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.quiz_container, resultFragment).commit()
    }

    private fun saveProgressData(
        selectedDifficulty : String,
        totalQuestionsPerGame : Int,
        totalCorrectAnswers : Int,
        totalWrongAnswers : Int,
        //averageScoresMap: Map<String, Double>
    ) {
        val totalQuestions = totalQuestionsPerGame

        // Save the progress data including the updated total questions answered, total correct answers,
        // total wrong answers, and average scores for the selected difficulty
        QuizProgressStorage.saveProgress(
            requireContext(),
            selectedDifficulty,
            totalQuestions,
            totalCorrectAnswers,
            totalWrongAnswers
        )
    }

}
```

and will be displayed here:

```
package com.mtcdb.stem.mathtrix.quiz

import android.os.*
import android.view.*
import android.widget.*
import androidx.fragment.app.*
import com.mtcdb.stem.mathtrix.*
import com.mtcdb.stem.mathtrix.quiz.QuizProgressStorage.calculateTotalValues
import com.mtcdb.stem.mathtrix.quiz.QuizProgressStorage.loadProgress

class QuizProgressFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var tvTotalQuestions : TextView
    private lateinit var tvTotalCorrectAnswers : TextView
    private lateinit var tvTotalWrongAnswers : TextView
    private lateinit var tvAverageScoreEasy : TextView
    private lateinit var tvAverageScoreMedium : TextView
    private lateinit var tvAverageScoreHard : TextView

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater : LayoutInflater, container : ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState : Bundle?,
    ) : View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_quiz_progress, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view : View, savedInstanceState : Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // Initialize TextViews
        tvTotalQuestions = view.findViewById(R.id.tvTotalQuestions)
        tvTotalCorrectAnswers = view.findViewById(R.id.tvTotalCorrectAnswers)
        tvTotalWrongAnswers = view.findViewById(R.id.tvTotalWrongAnswers)
        tvAverageScoreEasy = view.findViewById(R.id.tvAverageScoreEasy)
        tvAverageScoreMedium = view.findViewById(R.id.tvAverageScoreMedium)
        tvAverageScoreHard = view.findViewById(R.id.tvAverageScoreHard)

        val averageScores = QuizProgressStorage.loadAverageScores(requireContext())

        // Update the UI with the loaded progress data
        val progressDataMap = loadProgress(requireContext())
        val totalValues = calculateTotalValues(progressDataMap)

        tvTotalQuestions.text = totalValues[0].toString()
        tvTotalCorrectAnswers.text = totalValues[1].toString()
        tvTotalWrongAnswers.text = totalValues[2].toString()

        // Update average scores for each difficulty level
        averageScores.let { scores ->
            tvAverageScoreEasy.text = scores["Easy"]?.toString() ?: "N/A"
            tvAverageScoreMedium.text = scores["Medium"]?.toString() ?: "N/A"
            tvAverageScoreHard.text = scores["Hard"]?.toString() ?: "N/A"
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        (activity as? MainActivity)?.supportActionBar?.title = getString(R.string.app_name)
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

Can you help me identify any potential issues that might be causing the incorrect answers not to update correctly in the saveProgress function?

What modifications or adjustments can be made to ensure accurate tracking of total correct, incorrect, and unanswered questions in the application's progress data storage?

**What I've Tried:**

- Checked the logic in the saveProgress function multiple times to verify the calculations for updating total questions answered, total correct answers, and total incorrect answers.
- Reviewed the data loading process and data structures to ensure correctness in retrieving and updating progress data.
- Tested different scenarios with sample data to track how the incorrect answers count is being handled in the progress data storage.

**Expected Behavior:**

The saveProgress function is expected to increment the total number of questions answered, total correct answers, and total incorrect answers accurately based on the user's quiz responses. The total incorrect answers should reflect the actual count of incorrectly answered questions and shouldn't remain at 0 when incorrect answers are provided.